# Groups of order $pq$ for $p < q$ primes.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm going through an example in Dummit and Foote's $Abstract \; Algebra$ (page $143$ for those interested) and seek clarification.

Suppose $|G| = pq$ with $p < q$ primes. The claim is that if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup and $Q$ is a Sylow $q$-subgroup, then $Q$ is normal. If $P$ is normal, then $G = PQ$ is cyclic.

It is straightforward to show that $Q \unlhd G$ and that $n_{p} \in \{1, q\}$ (the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups in $G$). Suppose $p$ does not divide $q-1$. In this case, $P \unlhd G$.

What I do not follow is what comes next:

Let $P = \langle x \rangle$ and $Q = \langle y \rangle$. If $P \unlhd G$, then since the quotient $G / C_{G}(P)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(Z_{p})$ (which has order $p-1$), it must be the case that $G = C_{G}(P)$. In this case, $x \in P \leq Z(G)$, so $x, y$ commute. Hence $|xy| = pq$, so we can conclude $G$ is cyclic.

In particular, why can we assume that $P$ and $Q$ are cyclic? I'm also a bit unclear about why $G / C_{G}(P)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(Z_{p})$, but I think this follows from a result that for any subgroup $H \leq G$, the quotient group $N_{G}(H) / C_{G}(H)$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\text{Aut}(H)$.

Answer (score 3):

$P$ and $Q$ are cyclic because they have prime order. as for $\mathop{Aut},$ there is a map $\psi:G\rightarrow \mathop{Aut}(H),$ where $H$ is a normal subgroup, where $g$ goes to conjugation by $g.$ The kernel of this map is precisely the centralizer.

Comment: Thanks. I feel a bit silly having overlooked that.